# Add custom style button to wysiwyg in Advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to add a custom button to the wysiwyg editor in Advanced custom fields. I have not found any good solution on how to do it.

What I want is a button that wraps the selected text in `<span class="someclass"></span>` so that I can style this as I want.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839252/add-custom-button-to-tinymce-in-wordpress

Comment: Are u sure that there is not any simplified way of doing this with acf?

Comment: Just checked for the ACF wysiwyg seems you can use a filter on acf wysiwyg toolbars. See http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-wysiwyg-toolbars/

Comment: Though this is for already existing buttons. I think you'll need to create the button as described in the first link I sent anyway, then add it in ACF with the method of the second link.

Answer (score 7):

What you will need to do is tie into your TinyMCE editor buttons. This will add a format dropdown to your WYSIWYG editor for the class. You can then select your text and choose the class from the dropdown. Use text view to check to see if it worked.

```
/*
 * Callback function to filter the MCE settings
 */

// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2($buttons) {
    array_unshift($buttons, 'styleselect');
    return $buttons;
}

// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');

function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats($init_array) {
// Define the style_formats array
    $style_formats = array(
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(
            'title' => 'Some Class',
            'inline' => 'span',
            'classes' => 'someclass'
        ),
    );
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode($style_formats);
    return $init_array;
}

// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats');
```