# Add Visual Custom Button to TinyMCE in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, text-editor

if any unclaritites please tell me and i shall explain even further.
I want to add a visual button to my Classic editor on wordpress - tinymce. I've followed several guides including the one stated in [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839252/add-custom-button-to-tinymce-in-wordpress)

This plugin https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/visual-editor-custom-buttons/ made it work for the HTML section but doesnt show up visually. See images for better explanation

[image: text editor]

[image: visual editor]

I'm aware the plugin is old, however shouldnt be any major changes to the text editor ? Can't seem to find any working guides either.

You can find my code on pastebin:

```
`https://pastebin.com/F8Gfb30k`
`https://pastebin.com/xkACFRf4`
```